# What types of symbols are allowed in google analytics referral link?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I've just started using Google Analytics SDK for Android and I noticed (not sure in 100%) that I don't get referral links where `medium` contains dots. Could someone answer me what types of symbol are allowed to use in this [Google Campaign Generator](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/campaigns?hl=pl#campaign-params) ?

---

Dots are working.